# FPDF- SetFillColor

Tags: php, fpdf

Could anyone explain to me how this function in FPDF works? I can't seem to get any color from it, using this code:

```
function Header()
    {
        // Logo
        $this->Image($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/assets/documents/barcodes/'.$_SESSION["loggedin"].'.png',10,6,30);
        // Arial bold 15
        $this->SetFont('Arial','B',15);
        // Move to the right
        $this->Cell(80);
        // Title
        $this->Cell(75,25,'Technische beurs Sax',1,0,'C');
        // Line break
        $this->SetFillColor(0, 255, 0);
        $this->Ln(40);
    }
```

This function gets called in a class PDF that extends the normal FPDF class, according to this example: http://www.fpdf.org/en/tutorial/tuto2.htm.

For an example, this is what the "end result" should look like: 
http://technischforum.sax-professional.be/assets/documents/BevestigingMail.pdf

Answer (score 10, accepted):

SetFillColor doesn't work on the entire page,
to work around this add a rect and fill it

this is a black A4

```
$pdf->SetFillColor(0,0,0);
$pdf->Rect(0, 0, 210, 297, 'F');
```

then SetXY back to the required position

Answer (score 9):

`$this->Cell(75,25,'Technische beurs Sax',1,0,'C', ***1***);  // 1 for filling color`